# how to turn a 3 levels lines in notepad++ into csv

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have over 30000 record. all the same.

I want this format:

```
parent::name::description::slug

example:Uncategorized::New Category::This category is new::new-category
```

the file is like this:

```
Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets

Bakery & Confectionery

Chocolate



Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets

Bakery & Confectionery

Gum



Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets

Bakery & Confectionery

Candy Toys



Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets::Bakery & Confectionery::::Bakery-Confectionery    // this is subcategory of category Chocolate, Biscuits ...


Bakery & Confectionery::Chocolate::::Chocolate    // this is subcategory of subcategory

Bakery & Confectionery::Gum::::Gum    // this is subcategory of subcategory

Bakery & Confectionery::Candy Toys::::Candy-Toys    // this is subcategory of subcategory
```

can it be done using regex in notepad++?

Comment: Your description and examples are very confusing. Please give a clear indication of what a sample from the file looks like before and after. Also, what distinguishes a category from a description from a slug, etc.?

Comment: Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets is the category

Comment: Bakery & Confectionery is a subcategory

Comment: Chocolate is subcategory of subcategory Bakery & Confectionery

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this in Notepad++:

Find: `(.*)[\r\n]+(.*)[\r\n]+(.*)[\r\n]+`

Replace with: `$1::$2::::$3\r\n`

For your sample data:

```
Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets

Bakery & Confectionery

Chocolate

Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets

Bakery & Confectionery

Gum

Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets

Bakery & Confectionery

Candy Toys
```

The output is:

```
Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets::Bakery & Confectionery::::Chocolate
Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets::Bakery & Confectionery::::Gum
Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets::Bakery & Confectionery::::Candy Toys
```

Comment: I want this output

Comment: want this format parent::name::description::slug in the output you provided there is no subcatgories of subcatogories like the one in the question

Comment: I found the solution from your reply thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Hi Ramy, It wasn't really clear from your question exactly what you wanted. I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction to solve the problem.

Comment: do you have an idea how to replace spaces and &s with - after :::: in regex? Chocolate, Biscuits & Sweets::Bakery & Confectionery::::Candy-Toys

Comment: You can replace `(::::[^\s&]*)[\s&]+` with `$1-` but you might need to run `Replace All` more than once to get all occurrences.